# A bunch of random value binaries are generated by git or nextJS I think when I make a commit

Tags: node.js, git, next.js

I've put them in the trash but it seems that git or possible NextJS is creating these binary files, seemingly random, it would seem weird to have to delete them all the time, why are they being created if anyone has an idea that would be helpful thanks.

[image: files]
[image]

I'm now thinking it has to do with this code

```
import formidable from "formidable";
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// first we need to disable the default body parser
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function image(req, res) {
  try {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = "./";
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(files));

      // console.log(files);

      var oldPath = files.file.path;
      // var rawData = fs.readFileSync(oldPath);

      fs.readFile(oldPath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`Error reading file from disk: ${err}`);
        } else {
          // parse JSON string to JSON object
          const databases = JSON.parse(data);

          databases.shift();

          console.log(databases[0]);

          const final = databases.map((item, i) => {
            return { dateTime: item.field1 };
          });

          console.log(final[0]);
        }
      });
    });
    res.status(200).json({ message: "hello world" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(error.requestResult.statusCode).send(error.message);
  }
}
```

I copied the wrong file, I think this is the offending code

```
import formidable from "formidable";
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
let streamifier = require("streamifier");

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

// first we need to disable the default body parser
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function image(req, res) {
  try {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = "./";
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(files));

      console.log(files.image.path);

      var oldPath = files.image.path;
      var rawData = fs.readFileSync(oldPath);

      console.log(rawData);

      let cld_upload_stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
        {
          folder: "catalog",
        },
        function (error, result) {
          console.log(error, result);
          res.status(200).send({ result });
        }
      );

      streamifier.createReadStream(rawData).pipe(cld_upload_stream);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(error.requestResult.statusCode).send(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you create the commits with? If cli, what exact commands do you use? Are you using some git related shell plugin, e.g. with zsh? Could be something piping the commit hash. What do the files contain?

Comment: I use the cli. I was originally on linux but moved to mac for this repo. I run `git add .` and git commit -m "message" these files don't seem to always be created on commits, Im not sure where they are coming from. zsh is built into mac, but I'm not using any special plugin for git and zsh. In the file it's undreadable to me, but starts like so `?PNG

IHDRxB??AiCCPICC Profile(?c``H,(?aa``??+)
rwR???R`??? ??? ?`??\\??T??Q??k...`

Comment: That's interesting, that header appears to indicate it's a PNG file. If you add .png to the name of one of them, what does the image look like? Could it be some sort of a macOS thumbnail? Your repo is not inside a `.DS_Store` directory, is it?

Comment: oh they are images, so my app is using formidable to parse images on upload, I wonder if formidable temporarily saves the image File https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable and no not in a .DS_Store

Comment: I added the code that may be causing the problem

Comment: This seems to be a script to upload files and you have `form.uploadDir = "./"`. What would be the expected outcome?

Comment: I have added the correct code, I had copied old code before, the expected outcome is to get the buffer and send it to cloudinary which works.

Comment: Any reason why you're explicitly setting the `uploadDir` and not using the default value `os.tmpdir()`?

Comment: Not that I know of, I looked at a code example somewhere for this. I can use os.tmpdir() I will try that.

Comment: You can save files to wherever you see fit, but it shouldn't be a surprise that files end up in the directory you set. "Default" means that it's what you get when you don't do anything.

Comment: I ended up using `os.tmpdir()` if you wanted to write that as an answer I will select it. Otherwise I will for future reference. Thanks